# Send Arduino data via a Wi-Fi shield to a specific IP address on the LAN

Tags: arduino

I'm attempting to send sensor data from an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) via a [Copperhead Wi-Fi shield](http://www.robotshop.com/cuhead-wifi-shield-v2-0-arduino-3.html) to a specific IP address and port on a LAN.

I can get the Copperhead Wi-Fi Server example [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) to work (pasted below). However, I'm not interested in responding to server requests via HTML. All I'm interested in is setting up a socket-like connection and sending data via TCP or UDP to IP address 192.168.0.3, port 1234.

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this, but as I am new to Arduino and my attempts to find a solution have been unsuccessful.

```cpp
#include <WiServer.h>
#define WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA 1
#define WIRELESS_MODE_ADHOC 2

// Wireless configuration parameters ----------------------------------------
unsigned char local_ip[] = {192,168,0,2};   // IP address of WiShield
unsigned char gateway_ip[] = {192,168,0,1}; // router or gateway IP address
unsigned char subnet_mask[] = {255,255,255,0};  // subnet mask for the local network
const prog_char ssid[] PROGMEM = {"WiFi_AP"};       // max 32 bytes

unsigned char security_type = 0;    // 0 - open; 1 - WEP; 2 - WPA; 3 - WPA2

// WPA/WPA2 passphrase
const prog_char security_passphrase[] PROGMEM = {"12345678"};   // max 64 characters

// WEP 128-bit keys
// sample HEX keys
prog_uchar wep_keys[] PROGMEM = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,     0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, // Key 0
              0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Key 1
              0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Key 2
              0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  // Key 3
            };

// Setup the wireless mode
// Infrastructure - connect to AP
// Adhoc - connect to another Wi-Fi device
unsigned char wireless_mode = WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA;

unsigned char ssid_len;
unsigned char security_passphrase_len;
// End of wireless configuration parameters ----------------------------------------


// This is our page serving function that generates web pages
boolean sendMyPage(char* URL) {

    // Check if the requested URL matches "/"
    if (strcmp(URL, "/") == 0) {
        // Use WiServer's print and println functions to write out the page content
        WiServer.print("<html>");
        WiServer.print("Hello World");
        WiServer.print("</html>");

        // URL was recognized
        return true;
    }
    // URL not found
    return false;
}


void setup() {
    // Initialize WiServer and have it use the sendMyPage function to serve pages
    WiServer.init(sendMyPage);

    // Enable Serial output and ask WiServer to generate log messages (optional)
    Serial.begin(57600);
    WiServer.enableVerboseMode(true);
}

void loop(){
    // Run WiServer
    WiServer.server_task();

    delay(10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the `WiShield` library.  There should be an examples folder in the `WiShield` download with a `SocketApp` and `UDPApp` example. This is a good place to start.

A few things I learned while making a UDP app.

1. You may have to edit some #defines (*e.g. `APP_UDPAPP` in `apps-conf.h`, `UIP_CONF_UDP` in `uip-conf.h`*) before recompiling your app.
2. If you are doing a `UDP` app, keep in mind that you have a limited receive buffer (*`UIP_CONF_BUFFER_SIZE` in `uip-conf.h` sets it to **400***).  My router was sending out a UDP broadcast XML message that was **~700 bytes** which caused this buffer to overflow and over write other data.  I don't think TCP will have this problem because it will negotiate a MSS that won't overrun the buffer.

In the end I made changes to the `handle_connection()` function in the `UDPapp` example. Below is a snippet (*with `uip_ipaddr` set to `255.255.255.255`*).

```cpp
void send_state(void) {
    sprintf((char*)uip_appdata, "state %ld %ld %ld %c %d", 
    clock_time(), 
    state.sensors.ping[0].cm,
    state.sensors.ping[1].cm,
    state.actuators.chassis.direction,
    state.actuators.chassis.speed);
    uip_send(uip_appdata, strlen((char*)uip_appdata));
}

void send_beacon(void) {
    if(timer_expired(&beacon_timer)) {
        timer_reset(&beacon_timer);
        sprintf((char*)uip_appdata, "beacon %ld", clock_time());
        uip_send(uip_appdata, strlen((char*)uip_appdata));
        uip_log("beacon sent");
    }
}

boolean data_or_poll(void) {
    return (uip_newdata() || uip_poll());
}

static PT_THREAD(handle_connection(void)) {
    PT_BEGIN(&s.pt);
    PT_WAIT_UNTIL(&s.pt, data_or_poll());
    if(uip_newdata()) {
        uip_flags &= (~UIP_NEWDATA);
        send_state();
    } else if (uip_poll()) {
        uip_flags &= (~UIP_POLL);
        send_beacon();
    }

    PT_END(&s.pt);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks for the heads-up on buffer size, too!

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a chance to look at the [Arduino WiFiWebClient tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebClient)? This example shows how to connect to a webserver and send an HTTP GET request.

You could create a simple server on any machine on the LAN and use the client library to connect to the server and send data using the write/print/println set of functions. I know its easier said than done, but thats the fun of programming isnt it?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll explore this option, too.